# TypeError: Invalid Event Target - But just by using direct Route

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-routing

The application has the following component implemented

*customer-overview.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk'

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

import { CustomerOverviewService, CustomerOverviewDataSource } from './../../services/customer-overview.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'customer-overview-component',
    templateUrl: 'customer-overview.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customer-overview.component.css'],

    providers: [CustomerOverviewService]
})
export class CustomerOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    private _dataService: CustomerOverviewService;
    public dataSource: CustomerOverviewDataSource | null;

    @ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;

    constructor(private dataService: CustomerOverviewService, private router: Router) {
        this._dataService = dataService;
        this.dataSource = new CustomerOverviewDataSource(this._dataService);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
                .debounceTime(150)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribe(() => {
                    if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
                    this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
                });
    }
}
```

The routing itself is defined as following

*app.module.client.ts*

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent
        }
        {
            path: 'customer',
            component: CustomerOverviewComponent
        }
    ]


    @NgModule({
        bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
        declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
        imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
                appRoutes,
                { enableTracing: true }),
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            SharedModule,

        ],
        providers: [
            CustomerOverviewService,
            ...sharedConfig.providers,
            { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
        ]
    })
```

The component works fine without any error via the console or getting a 500 via the network protocol. But when I use the direct link to localhost/customer, I get the following error.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error:
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Invalid event target
>   TypeError: Invalid event target
>   at Function.FromEventObservable.setupSubscription

I tried to use the *Observable.FromEvent* in an NgAfterViewInit and in the constructor, but none of this helped. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you done :     <base href="/"> ?

Comment: Yes, it's in my _Layout.cshtml.

I deploy the Angular application via .NET Core MVC

Comment: How do you inject ORIGIN_URL? look at that part

Comment: It's a default layout I use. Everything works just fine if I leave the Observable.fromEvent() out.

Comment: It's not Observable.fromEvent() the problem but how you get your data from the backend

Comment: Without changing anything but a restart of the environment it works now flawless. Thanks Vega

Comment: Great! i am not sure I help you though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move your subscription to `ngAfterVewInit` hook.

The fact is that `@ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;` initialize before `ngAfterVewInit` but after `ngOnInit`. So you place undefined value to `fromEvent` operator.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.searchField);
    Observable.fromEvent(this.searchField.nativeElement, 'input').
    map((e: any) => e.target.value).
    filter(text => text.length > 2).
    debounceTime(1000).
    distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Works fine.